# Backup apps in ipa format on iphone no PC

Tags: backup, iphone, restore, firmware

I need to restore my iphone firmware on my work computer, without installing any other program other than the iTunes already installed on it. I'm wondering if there's some kind if app or jailbreak tweak I can install on the iphone  and use to back up all my apps into ipa, copy to PC, then install later again.( I could always use appcake to install back )

Comment: What 'work computer'? Why do you think you can 'restore' firmware for device X on an completely different device Y?

Comment: if the phone is currently working, then backing it up to its regular iTunes would do that for you. Apps are ephemeral anyway, they're always available from the App Store, once purchased.

Answer (score 1):

Techicnally, what you want isn't impossible, but is pretty hard. I'd SSH in via your work computer, and copy applications from `/var/mobile/Applications/`. (`/var/movile/Container/Applications/` in iOS 8). And, even that doesn't restore *all* your data.

Comment: Tried that. But the directory /var/mobile/applications/. Only contains folder. Not ipa.

Comment: @user400491 those basically are unziped IPA's. You'll never have the true IPA on the device -- its deleted after getting unziped. So, those folder are your applications and all of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Well I guess id forget about them apps and just go on and restore the firmware.  But still thank you.

Comment: Ok. Glad I could help!

Comment: the only apps you can't get back with the click of a button are the ones you don't have on your iTunes account.

Comment: I was going to add that even iTunes doesn't back up all your data.